# Is GitHub remote repository is created using the --bare flag?

Tags: git

My local repository is created using `git init`. I wonder if the remote repository, on GitHub was created using `git init --bare`?

Comment: Given that [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) has provied an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56917237/267), may I ask why you ask?

Comment: Sure. I think its better to understand how things are working under the hood in a service I use and like so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub most likely use a special modified version of Git with a lot of special GitHub-specific tweaks, so they may well have their own flag that is like `--bare` only fancier.  But that aside, yes: repositories on GitHub are effectively `--bare` repositories.